# How long will 12V DC 8 Amps power supply work on 13 Amps load

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current

I know that I should use 12V DC and at least 13 Amps.

And that I can use power supply with even more amps.

But I am interested if I use only 8 Amps, what I have available, how long it will last ?

Will it be like in minutes days, weeks, months ?

Comment: Approximately 850µs

Comment: @PlasmaHH I think your are out by a decimal point.

Comment: @Andyaka: We might have different definitions of "last", mine includes "until flames emerge".

Comment: Since months, weeks, and days are all made from minutes and you've specified no finer granularity,  I'd say "minutes".

Comment: If its anything like the 12V 2A switching supplies I have, it will shut down when a large load is placed. In my case it's a stalled dremel/rotary tool/motor. I'm sure it's nothing good for the supply.

Comment: This is a ridiculous question as there is no way to give a responsible answer without knowing the details of the supply.

Answer (score 2):

Depends.
If the power supply has over current protection it will shut off and nothing bad will happen - it is just that whatever you are trying to power won't work.

If it doesn't have over current protection, anything could happen.

It might release its magic smoke in the 850µS that PlasmaHH1 mentions, and it might run for some time delivering too little current and too little voltage before it quietly quits (best case if there's a fuse in the transformer itself) or explodes or catches fire or melts down onto your workbench.

Answer (score 1):

If the PSU is switchmode the prognosis won't be good like JRE says.

If it is just a transformer and a bridge rectifier and a filter cap which was the norm in earlier decades but now less common then you could be in luck.

Taking more current will sag the voltage down and increase the ripple. The increased ripple can be dealt with by placing more electrolytic capacitance across the output.  Thousands of microfarads at 16V or more. This cap increase wont fully recover the sag so you may still have a 11V supply. In fact it can be shown that infinite capacitance wont get the DC back to where it was. If your load doesn't mind then you can run the PSU intermittantly. So you could run the load at a 25% duty cycle for minutes not hours.

Comment: This permissable intermittant overload stuff is the key for automotive jump starting .Imagine if the transformer has larger than normal diodes and larger than normal electrolytic cap after it ,Then its followed by a low drop high current linear regulator .Now if the transformer has the more expensive self resetting thermal overload you are in bussiness .So all this means that if the load is intermittant the  oldschool  PSU can be cheaper ,more reliable and sometimes smaller than a switchmode bought off the shelf .If you have to pass mil 461 EMC then its a real winner.